# How can I check if an ActiveX dll is already registered?

Tags: activex

I have an installer that is registering several dll's and need to know if this was successful.

Comment: What installer technology are you using?

Comment: i'm using installshield and the "com extract at build" option on the dll

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do the trick for me:  http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html

Answer (score 2):

I would like to let you know all registered COM class objects are listed under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\.` We can navigate to this location in registry editor, highlight `CLSID` and press Ctrl+F to search the `dll/ocx` file.