# Error 429 Excel VBA activex CreateObject(“SAP.Functions”)

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, sap-gui, saprfc

I just upgraded to Windows 10 and Excel 2016 and now my VBA app doesn't work:

```
set x = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
```

I get this error:

> runtime error 429 ActiveX component can’t create object

Comment: Excel 32-bit, or 64-bit?  There are two versions and using 64-bit often leads to issues like this. BTW Those quotes look wrong, unless you re-typed that code.

Comment: Excel 2016 32-bit

Comment: Is the SAP component installed and registered?

Comment: Its installed, how do I check if its registered?

Comment: I don't know anything about that component, so I would just try re-installing it.

Comment: my question isn't component specific.

Comment: `CreateObject(“SAP.Functions”)` isn't component-specific?  I'm not sure I"m following you here.  Maybe try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510171/how-can-i-check-if-an-activex-dll-is-already-registered

Comment: your question had two parts. 1. is it installed? A: yes, 2. is it registered? A: I would assume so.  Whats the difference between installed and registered?  Your question implies a difference.

Comment: A component can be installed (dll's etc are actually present on the system) but not registered for use as a COM object (see the link I posted earlier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install Office 32-bit version.  For some reason the 64-bit Office doesn't support the "SAP.Functions" even though the SAP DLLs and OCXs were correctly installed and registered.

Comment: Hi Tom...it's been a couple of years and I'm wondering if you know if this issue has been rectified. My thought was that SAP has not updated their rfc-related library files to work with 64-bit Office...maybe they have by now. I need 64-bit to work so Excel can use more than 1.6GB of memory to extract a huge table out of SAP. This task crashes on a 32-bit Excel on a VM when Excel RAM use hits 1.6GB. If I can't make this work, I'm going to have to figure out how to split the job into smaller pieces...doable (I think), but as you may know this can be a pain to manage.

Comment: also, check for "ALGORITM" on http://www.fastgeneticalgorithmsoftware.com/

Comment: Good catch on my spelling...my fix from 2 years ago is still working so I haven't touched it.